# error "Runtime error"

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I need help here. I don't understand why it keeps getting (Runtime error    time: 0 memory: 3460 signal:11)

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void CountEvenNumber(int N, int *e);

 main()
 {
      int e;
      int i;
      int N;
      printf("Insert total data : \n");scanf("%d", N);

       for(i=1;i<=N; i++)
       {
              CountEvenNumber(N, &e);
       }
       printf("Total = %f", &e);
 }

void CountEvenNumber(int data, int *even)
{
       *even = 0+2;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &N);`

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Also, turn on a reasonable warning level, all of those errors are easily detected by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the number of even numbers below the entered number
    #include

```
 void CountEvenNumber(int N, int *e);

 int main()
 {
      int e = 0;  //initialize the e by 1 otherwise there is chase to get a garbage value.
      int i;
      int N;
      printf("Insert total data : \n");
      scanf("%d", &N);

       for(i=1;i<=N; i++)
       {
          if((i % 2) == 0) //check whether the number is even
          {
              CountEvenNumber(N, &e);
          }
       }
       printf("Total = %d", e);
 }

void CountEvenNumber(int data, int *even)
{
  *even = *even + 1;  //increment even by 1
}
```

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to count even numbers. Could you please tell me how to do it right? I'm still newbie here.

Comment: @T2WGWatch Does the code Ajay provided not work for you, or are you having trouble working why Ajay's code works and yours doesn't?